# Help finding resistor

Tags: resistors, identification

I have a resistor on a power supply for an amplifier.  It has failed and I am trying to find a replacement.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've only ever played with low voltage stuff and this is dealing with higher power and voltages thsn I am used to.

The capacitor beside it had also blown which I was able to replace (not in this picture.)

[image: blown out resistor]

Answer (score 1):

The color codes are blown away, nobody is going to know for sure what value that's supposed to be without a schematic

There's a little color left .. Brown & Black ...  And judging by the physical size of it (1/2W ??), I would I'd bet a lunch it's either 1 ohm, 10 ohm or 100 ohm.    1000 ohm wouldn't likely be such a big part (wouldn't get hot so no need for that size).  Brown/Black means "10".  The rest is conjecture

Also note that the cap may have blown, and the resistor may have blown, but that doesn't mean those were the bad parts.   If something else failed (like especially a rectifying diode failing short), those parts could have been destroyed by it.   In other words, you may get this done, plug it in, and it'll blow again.  Resistors and small caps like that don't generally catastrophically fail w/o some external stimulus causing it.

Comment: Caps fail on their own without any other reason. Capacitor plague

Comment: Of course I'm aware of that.  Everything can fail.  But we're talking generalities ... I stated what "usually" happens, not what "could" happen.. There's not enough space to list all those possibilities, is there???   "Capacitor Plague" was a brief moment in time and ended almost 20 years ago, and did not affect every capacitor on the planet.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague     Further they usually just leaked... no evidence of electrolyte in the picture provided.   More likely IN MY OPINION is that cap failed because the resistor failed, overheated, and it 'blew it's top'.